# GCE VM instance reset and unable to connect to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, google-compute-engine

Failure to connect to mongodb after VM instance is reset.I get the following error 
"Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused" 
tried the following, but did not work

$ sudo service mongodb start

$ sudo mongod --repair

Comment: Perhaps your mongodb service isn't set to start automatically on reboot?

Comment: Is there a way to set it up? I tried to check but could not find a way to connect to the server. I deleted the mongod-27017.sock file to check if I can reconnect, but that did not work either.

Comment: Sure you can set a service to start automatically. What's O/S image do you use?

Comment: ```sudo systemctl enable mongodb``` should enable mongodb to start on reboot

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall mongodb worked.

Comment: great, glad to hear it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your MongoDB service is not set to to start automatically on server's reboot. You will need to either reinstall the mongodb or set the service to start on reboot by using `sudo systemctl enable mongodb`